# Increase in size of compiled templates.js in ember 1.11.3

Tags: javascript, ember.js, htmlbars

Once we migrated to ember 1.11.3 from 1.10.1 my compiled templates.js file size increased from ~5MB to ~9MB, without even changing any template(.hbs) file or adding any hbs file. I'm using HTMLBars in my templates. Anyone know the reason for it?

Comment: new template features need new runtime support? can you post a before and after for us? (i'm curious...)

Comment: after moving to HTMLBars we need ember-template-compiler for compiling templates, but for handlebars we don't need that.

Comment: it likely needs more meta to handle live vdom updating that's not needed to render out a string one time...

Comment: oh, okay. will the size get reduced if I upgrade my app to latest ember or HTMLBars version? any idea?

Comment: Seems unlikely. New format should compress better though, which should reduce the total effective increase once in production.